# Loading Youtube in a modal (possibly with swfobject?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, swfobject

I'm having a lot of problems getting a YouTube video to load in a modal properly on all browsers.  I just found swfobject but can't find any code on implementing it.

Can anyone tell me how to load a YouTube video dynamically using swfobject?  I've also got jQuery running on the site if that makes it more elegant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  This is the code I used to get it to work in the modal:

```
var atts = {};
atts.id = "vid";
$.modal('<div class="modal_container" style="background: transparent url(<?php echo $base_path . path_to_theme() ?>/images/bkgd_youtube_modal.png) no-repeat;"><div id="youtube_movie"></div></div>', options);

swfobject.embedSWF('http://www.youtube.com/v/'+this.id+"&hl=en&fs=1&rel=0&color1=0x000000&color2=0x2d2d2d&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer",
"youtube_movie", "460px", "280px", "9", null, null, atts);
```